# Using rvm, rubygems and bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

So, I've done a lot of Rails programming in the past and now I came to a point where I just want to use Ruby with RVM and Bundler and some other gems.. But after I got all set up I required the gem I wanted to use in this project and got the following LoadError:

```
.rvm/../custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- upnp/ssdp (LoadError)
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

I've got the following files:

```
upnp
- Gemfile
- upnp.rb
```

Than in the Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile

source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "upnp", git: "https://github.com/turboladen/upnp.git"
```

And the project main file:

```
# upnp.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'upnp/ssdp'

# Search for all devices (do an M-SEARCH with the ST header set to 'ssdp:all')
all_devices = UPnP::SSDP.search

puts all_devices
```

Now, after setting up RVM with a gemset, and bundled everything, when I run:

```
ruby upnp.rb
```

I get this error mentioned above..

I've checked out the Github page of this gem and it has a `lib` folder with `upnp/ssdp.rb`

So should be good right?

I really don't know how to debug such a thing!

Can someone shine a light on this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a call to `bundle exec`.  Below is with Ruby 1.93p194

```
$ bundle exec ruby upnp.rb 
D, [2012-11-06 11:05:06 #48555] DEBUG -- : Sent datagram search:
D, [2012-11-06 11:05:06 #48555] DEBUG -- : M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
```

I can't find the reference, but rvm/ruby has problems finding rubygems that are "git installed".  Googling will probably turn up the official answer.

Comment: Wow, great, this seems to work! I did know about bundle exec, but never took the chance to find out when I should use it.. Guess this is a good time to find out more about that piece of code.. Thanks!

Comment: I think using the latest version of RVM (head) makes it so you don't need to use bundle exec.

Comment: Could be.  I'm only at RVM 1.16.11.